# WIll the unity 8 mir be usable in 16.04 LTS release?

Tags: unity8, 16.04

Expecting the Unity 8 to be available as a daily use gui like unity 7. Is that possible or it will be just for testing?

Comment: Available?,  maybe,  usable?, no.

Answer (score 1):

Unity 8 will definitely be standard with upcoming releases. It is already available for you to preview if you want to get a feel for it.

This is a great article on it: http://news.softpedia.com/news/unity-8-all-you-need-to-know-494057.shtml

Comment: Any information on what release would include unity8? This is not much use with out that information, you don't even answer if it will be in 16.04 (fyi no it won't) please edit your answer with some substance and I will give yo a +1

Comment: Yeah the link says maybe in 16.10 (changeable), some pages say that we will get two options during login and few sites are like we can use two different (with unity 7 or unity8) distros. Can you provide a strong  information?